# Tablesorter doesn't do anything in jQueryUI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, tablesorter

I am trying to use tablesorter upon a dynamically created table in a jquery ui dialog, but the tablesorter doesn't seem to work. That means the result is a simple html table without sorting or layout like tablesorter's "zebra". 
My code:

```js
var content = '<table id="searchtable" class="tablesorter"><thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Subject</th></th></tr>';
content += '</thead><tbody><tr><td>04.10.2016 09:00</td><td>some Text</td></tr>';
content += '<tr><td>04.10.2016 12:00</td><td>another Text</td></tr></tbody></table>';


$("#searchButton").button().click(function() {
  $('#searchdialog').html(content).dialog({
    width: "auto",
    open: function() {
      $('#searchtable').tablesorter();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tablesorter {
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  widgets: ['zebra'];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/css/theme.blue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<div id='searchButton'>Search</div>
<div id="searchdialog" title="Search Dialog"></div>
```

This is my first question at stackoverflow, and I'm not quite familiar with inserting code etc., I copied/pasted the code from my jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/JMKivi/kumrgyaw/12/). So please let me know if there are mistakes in using stackoverflow or something important seems to be missing.
Edit: I changed `<button id='searchButton'>Search</button>` to `<div id='searchButton'>Search</div>` now. It still works here but not in jsfiddle and in my production environment. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I get this Error:

```
Error: {
  "message": "TypeError: $(...).button is not a function",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 24,
  "colno": 1
}
```

This means you have to modify your selector to: (remove the button())

```
$("#searchButton").click(function()
```

```js
var content = '<table id="searchtable" class="tablesorter"><thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Subject</th></th></tr>';
content += '</thead><tbody><tr><td>04.10.2016 09:00</td><td>some Text</td></tr><tr><td>01.10.2016 09:00</td><td>some Text</td></tr>';
content += '<tr><td>04.10.2016 12:00</td><td>another Text</td></tr></tbody></table>';


$("#searchButton").click(function() {
  $('#searchdialog').html(content).dialog({
    width: "auto",
    open: function() {
      $('#searchtable').tablesorter();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tablesorter {
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  widgets: ['zebra'];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.27.8/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<button id='searchButton'>Search</button>
<div id="searchdialog" title="Search Dialog"></div>
```

Yeah this seems to work, just click on the headings ;)

Comment: "$("#searchButton").click()" and "$("#searchButton")button().click()" both work in jsfiddle. But the tablesorter doesn't sort anyway :(

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that it sorts now. Thank you! edit: well, it sorts here, but not in Jsfiddle and in my production environment.

Comment: It works for me in jsFiddle too. - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfucctw1/)
I mentioned, that your link to jquery.js had a wrong url: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js.  - remove the dot at the end :)

Comment: Thank you. Case of "Copy&Paste"-Error ;)  Works fine in jsfiddle now, but still doesn't in my production environment. Have to re-write that page, I think.